# GAE: Getting key of entity just created

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm creating a new entity like:

```
some_model = ModelName(
    attr1 = ...,
    attr2 = ...,
    attr3 = ...,
    attr4 = ...
).put()
```

Is there anyway to get the key of this newly created entity? I tried doing `some_model.key()` put that does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of the put() method is the key of the newly inserted entity. You can also call .key() on the model - *after* you've inserted it.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently some_model is the key.